# Wpgraphql- make data private

Tags: wordpress, graphql

I want to make data private (to return null when query is fetched).
I know that there is graphql_data_is_private filter, but I don't know how to implement my query, there's no example in docs.

Docs (https://www.wpgraphql.com/filters/graphql_data_is_private/):

```
apply_filters( 'graphql_data_is_private', bool $is_private, string $model_name, mixed $data, string $visibility, int $owner, WP_User $current_user );
```

My query:

```
query MyQuery {
  users {
    edges {
      node {
        lastName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a query option, it's a BE definition, you should add a filter (in your plugin or theme code) to modify (adapt to your needs) standard BE behaviour. This filter (hook) (for queried object) is used to check if data should be returned.

```
add_filter('graphql_data_is_private', 'add_graphql_private_visibility_filter', 10, 6);

function add_graphql_private_visibility_filter($is_private, $model_name, $data, $visibility, $owner, $current_user)
{
  if ('UserObject' === $model_name) {
    // if( is_your_allowed_data_condition ) return false;
    return true;
  }

  // return not changed for other objects
  return $is_private;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, you can use the GraphQL API for WordPress, which has native access control: https://graphql-api.com/guides/use/defining-access-control/

Then you can disable the field, or grant access to some users only, and make it private.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this plugin.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](/help/deleted-answers).